# Detecting number of CPU cores on Android from native code

Tags: android, c++, linux, multithreading, android-ndk

I'm using `sysconf( _SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN )` (which, I believe, is the recommended way) to get the number of CPU cores. It works fine or Mac and Linux, but on my 4-core Android tablet it returns 2. How can I get the actual number of cores on Android from native code (without using JNI to call Java Android API)?

Comment: Which CPU arch you're using? And, did you check on Linux?

Comment: I remember seeing this bug on Android that returns the number of active CPU at the first time the method is called, not the number of CPU present on the device: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26490

Comment: @rakib: ARM. Check what?

Comment: Is it big.LITTLE ? Did you find 4-core via /proc/cpuinfo ?

Comment: @rakib: I doubt it's big.LITTLE, it should be just a regular 4-core ARMv7a. I didn't look at /proc/cpuinfo, I just know the CPU has 4 cores. If I hardcode `4` for the the number of threads, I can see 100% CPU load and an appropriate performance boost.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I don't think this info gonna help, you're guessing here. Please try to get the actual info.

Comment: @rakib: I'm not guessing, I know the specs for my device. The number 4 is beyond question, the question is how to get this number reliably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `sysconf( _SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN )` nor `sysconf( _SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF )` works, but `android_getCpuCount()` from [cpufeatures](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/CPU-FEATURES.html) NDK library works correctly.

Comment: As noted in http://b.android.com/26490, as of NDK r7c the sysconf() call should be returning reasonable values.  Are they both returning 2 while android_getCpuCount() returns 4?  If so, please file a bug with that information and the output of "adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo".

Comment: @fadden: I'm using NDK r9 and both `sysconf( _SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN )` and `sysconf( _SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF )` return 2, while `android_getCpuCount()` returns 4.